# Are these sentences similar in meaning or just the opposite? "I felt I needed to leave". VS "I thought I needed to leave."

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

We as non-native speakers were taught that the structures such as **"I think"** and **"I feel"** are used to give your opinions. They are mostly the same but **"the degree of certainty"** is different. OK, so far, so good.

But if you just see the following example, they don't quite seem similar. When simply by replacing **"I felt"** with **"I thought"**, it is not only the **"degree of certainty"** that changes, but the whole meaning does.

**I felt I needed to leave.**

**I thought I needed to leave.**

The second sentence seems to have a different meaning from the first one. In that sentence, the speaker seems to be be surprised that he/she didn't need to leave but he/she thought so, whereas in the first sentence, there is no such meaning.

So, **"I felt"** and **"I thought"** do not seem to have the same meaning, let alone "having close meanings".

So, why do they still say **"I think"** and **"I feel"** are similar except for the degree of certainty. They don't seem to be similar but quite the opposite, aren't they?

Comment: The second sentence only has that meaning **if** it is followed by "but I found out that I didn't have to", or something to the same effect.

Comment: @KateBunting, thanks, so you say " if it is NOT followed by "but I found out that I didn't have to" it has the same meaning as the sentence starting with "I felt.....". But then why do we usually say things like "I thought you were ......" OR "I thought you would ........" when things turned out to be the opposite of what we expected them to be?

Comment: "Think" is supported by *reason* and "feel" relates to *emotion*. So, "think" should be supported by arguments and "feel" refers to a state of mind.

Comment: As we often say on these forums, _it all depends on the context_. "I thought it was very kind of you to [do that]"  is a comment on a past action. "I thought you were away on holiday!" (I'm surprised to see you here.) "I thought he didn't look well when I saw him last week." (I'm _not_ surprised to hear that he is ill.)